# Excel SUMIFS Array in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have an Excel sheet of time series data of prices where each day consists of 6 hourly periods. I am trying to use Python and Pandas which I have setup and working, importing a CSV and then creating a df from this. That is fine it is just the sorting code I am struggling with. In excel I can do this using a Sum(sumifs) array function but I would like it to work in Python/Pandas.

I am looking to produce a new time series from the data where for each day I get the average price for periods 3 to 5 inclusive only, excluding the others. I am struggling with this.

An example raw data exert and result I am looking for is below:

[image: Example data]

Comment: Do you mean that the average price will be calculated only over the rows where period equals to 3 or 5?

Comment: So for example, for 01/01/2017 I would like the average(Period = 3 and 4 and 5), the next day should be the same and so forth. So in the resulting series, you have one value per day which is the average of periods 3 to 5 on that day only.

Comment: One small advice - change data to text for possible copy it for prevent downvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need filter by [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and then aggregate `mean`:

```
df = df[df['Period'].between(3,5)].groupby('Date', as_index=False)['Price'].mean()
```

Comment: Genius thanks! Apologies, how do I get the new dataframe to display the dates as the index?

Comment: @Reno - Only remove `as_index=False` for `Series`, if want DataFrame then use `df[df['Period'].between(3,5)].groupby('Date')['Price'].mean().to_frame()`

Comment: I think I am having an issue as the date fields in the output are not as expected. I think I need to set the dtype of the 'date' field as a date. How do I do that? Thanks

Comment: @Reno - use `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])`